# Relation on $\mathbb{N}$ that is only transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Can a relation on $\mathbb{N}$ be only transitive, not reflexive nor symmetric nor antisymmetric?

I started with the usual $<$ that only satisfies transitivity but also antisymmetry. Then I tried adding some pair $(a,b)$
to my relation, violating antisymmetry. But in every try either reflexity or symmetry were satisfied then…

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  As a hint, I suggest trying simple examples.  Maybe start with a finite set.

Comment: A second hint: you can just make up your own relations pure for the purpose of answering your own question. The relation needs not to be 'natural' or 'meaningful' or useful in the context of numbers to be a relation - anything that satisfies the definition could be your answer

Comment: @Vincent, I started with the usual < that only satisfies transitivity but also antisymmetry. Then I tried adding some pair $(a,b)$ to my relation, violating antisymmetry. But in every try either reflexity or symmetry were satisfied then…

Comment: Yes. If a relation is not reflexive then it must be irreflexive, and a transitive relation is irreflexive if and only if it is also asymmetric. Asymmetry is distinct from symmetry and antisymmetry which were the only other two properties you ruled out, so there does exist at least one relation fitting your criteria (and this goes for any set, not just $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: @H.sapiensrex ok, and how would you construct such a relation?

Comment: Your initial guess of $\lt$ works perfectly. It is transitive: $a\lt b$ and $b\lt c$ implies $a\lt c$. It is irreflexive: for all $a$, it is not true that $a\lt a$. It is asymmetric: for all $a$ and $b$, if $a\lt b$, then it is not true that $b\lt a$. Hang on! I just remembered, a relation is asymmetric if and only if it is both irreflexive and antisymmetric... so actually, the answer to your query is "no"

Comment: @H.sapiensrex so there is no relation satisfying my requirements?

Comment: That's right, none. Sorry for getting your hopes up lol

Comment: @lulu Isn‘t antisymmetry defined as $xRy \wedge yRx \implies x=y$? Then asymmetry is satisfied in your example, isn’t it?

Comment: Ah, I've mixed up anti-   and a- symmetry.  My error,  I'll delete my example.

Comment: hmm not possible, that is kind of surprising. We learn something every day

Comment: @H.sapiensrex "If a relation is not reflexive then it must be irreflexive" huh??

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen it's a tautology; what's your confusion exactly?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex irreflexive means that *every* $x$ has $x\not R x$, not “not reflexive”. Anne’s example of a relation satisfying op’s criteria is neither reflexive nor irreflexive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example is the relation $\{1,2\}^2\cup\{(3,4)\}.$